# In QT5.5.1 example FancyBrowser (WebEngine-based) is crashed at the exit

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I have problem with my application, but after some hours of disabling everything, i've figured out that standart example FancyBrowser application (webengine-based) have the same issue.

It caused some break point somewhere deep in QtWebEngineCore (unfortunaltely in 5.5.1 they forgot to put symbols QtWebEngineCored.dll.pdb). And then application just quit.

Also, after this exception appearing some debug.log file:

```
  [1121 / 22 1113:FATAL : resource_scheduler.cc(784)] Check failed : client_map_.empty().
  Backtrace :
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182F75D06 + 47210422]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E243DD + 45827725]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x00000001806CD0FC + 4576172]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x000000018041B27C + 1750316]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x000000018041A95E + 1747982]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x000000018044643F + 1926895]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000180446245 + 1926389]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000180425820 + 1792720]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000180427791 + 1800769]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000180423FCA + 1786490]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000180427161 + 1799185]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x00000001802EFE5D + 524557]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182FA9D52 + 47423490]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E417C2 + 45947506]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E3EE11 + 45936833]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E3F564 + 45938708]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182FAE69C + 47442252]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182FB02C0 + 47449456]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182FB0215 + 47449285]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E41513 + 45946819]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E8AF2B + 46248411]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182E41395 + 45946437]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182EBD30D + 46454205]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x00000001803553E6 + 939670]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x000000018035696C + 945180]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182EBDF9F + 46457423]
  QtWebEngineCore::URLRequestCustomJobDelegate::qt_static_metacall[0x0000000182EDB67D + 46577965]
  BaseThreadInitThunk[0x0000000076FC652D + 13]
  RtlUserThreadStart[0x00000000771FC541 + 33]
```

It appears only in 5.5.1 (5.4.x never seen).
Just curious, is there something I can do with that ?

Comment: Probably you can build Qt 5.6 and see if the same happens again?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of the debug port,you can remove debug port param and have a try

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you don't delete the QWebEngineView when exiting the program. See discussion on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50160, although a much simpler solution is to just create the QWebEngineView on the stack.